# In WPF, how to check/uncheck a checkbox on 1/0 or y/n entered by user

Tags: wpf, wpf-4.0

I have a checkbox in a user control. I want the user to be able to check the checkbox when he enters y or 1, and to uncheck it when n or 0 is entered.

Better to have it all in XAML if possible.

Thank you in advance, your help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a `KeyBinding` to the `UserControl` to respond to the key presses in XAML, but you would still need to write a `Command` that changes the binding property.

```
<UserControl.InputBindings>
    <KeyBinding Key="Y" Command="{Binding MyCommand}" />
    <KeyBinding Key="N" Command="{Binding MyCommand}" />
    <KeyBinding Key="D0" Command="{Binding MyCommand}" />
    <KeyBinding Key="D1" Command="{Binding MyCommand}" />
</UserControl.InputBindings>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply; is there a possibility to have a xaml solution, like triggers? I mean, change the IsChecked or its binding property directly from xaml without writting code behind or mvvm?

Comment: Please see my edit. It would not be possible to avoid code completely, but a simple Command would allow you to change the state of the checkbox while defining most everything in XAML.

Comment: If there is no way other than writing the command code, then we have no other choice, have we?